# Applications camera on App Store is working slower than test version

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store

We have encountered a really strange issue and would like to ask if anyone had the same problems in their practice.

In the application we have implemented latest Apples example of custom camera using `AVFoundation`. As I have said we have followed their example thoroughly and call all phases in recommended order, the only change we have made is that we have separated camera management into a separate class, but we have provided a sufficient interface for interaction.

`ViewController` that contains camera preview view may lead to two other standard screens which do not demand a lot of time for initialisation (at least it is not visible). Transition happens via `NavigationController`.

In our tests in debug mode and via `Testflight` and `HockeyApp` (AdHoc certificate for the last two) the application ran flawlessly without any lags. But when we ran version from the App Store, which has the same code, we noted that transitions to the `ViewController` with camera and from it stuck for 2-4 seconds. We have checked both the code and Internet for possible causes and similar issues, but have not found anything.

So, have anyone here encountered same issues with camera, or situations when released application behaved that much differently, and, maybe, can tell us in what direction we should dig?

Please tell us if you need any additional information.

Comment: Try measuring a build with stripped symbols with Instruments.

Answer (score 0):

One thing, which could make the results of your test and release binaries different is a compiler optimisation level settings. AVFoundation loves dispatch queues and aggressive optimisation could cause you block main queue somewhere. Instruments might be helpful.

**EDIT**

It is possible to use Time Profile to analyse what happens. You need to attach it to the process, select the correct .dSYM and measure. Once you will find the longest call, you could optimise it.

Comment: `AdHoc` and `AppStore` builds use the same optimisation settings. How exactly `Instruments` can help here?

Comment: Does it possible to do this for the app that has been downloaded from AppStore?

Comment: Archive your product for submission to iTunes Connect. An archive is a bundle that includes your product along with symbol information. You can build an archive to seed an application for testing or to validate and submit an application to iTunes Connect.